# How to filter one column on table with datatable.js?

Tags: datatables

I have data in the table, from that table I added a dropdown menu that is used to filter columns based on status.

Where the status in the dropdown menu is:
**"All"** to display all data.

**"Done"** to display data with the status "Done"

**"In Progress"** to display data with the status "In Progress"

**"Rejected"** to display data with the status "Rejected".
[image]
The code I made is like [this](https://hastebin.com/exunexuxon.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`column().search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search())

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    'sDom': 'lrtip',
    'paging': true,
    'lengthChange': false,
    'info': true,
  });

  $('select').on('change', function() {
    table.column(5).search(this.value).draw()
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<p align="right">
  <label>Filter :</label>
  <select style="color:black;width:235px;" class="w3-input" name="report_type" required="required">
    <option value="" selected>All</option>
    <option value="Done">Submitted</option>
    <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
    <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
  </select>
</p>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>Done</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>Done</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>In Progress</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>In Progress</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>In Progress</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>Rejected</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>Done</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>In Progress</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>Rejected</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008/12/13</td>
      <td>Done</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>Done</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>In Progress</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```